# Trigger event from JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Let me try and be as much clear as possible although it won't be easy. OK, I have a circle inside div, and I know the x and y coordinates of the circle inside this div.

How could I create JavaScript or HTML tooltip to point at the spot where I clicked (in this case the circle)?

Here is the image so you can better understand what I'm trying to do:

[Here is the picture](http://i34.tinypic.com/2vv3thk.png)

Now I know some of you will think: why not just use the id of circle and get the tooltip to point to that direction? Well because the circle is dynamically created as a JavaScript object and is not part of the HTML.

Because drawing saves time: where can I find a tooltip script pointing from above? Something like this, here goes another:

[Screen shot](http://i33.tinypic.com/24mdrbn.jpg)

Comment: You should be able to programmatically add a click handler to the circle, when clicked you'd have access to the top/left values for the circle and should be able to instantiate whatever you need at the appropriate location. Not posting this as an answer as it's just a pointer to get you looking in a right direction.

Comment: Thank you Lazarus for your guidance, I can't add it because I didn't write rest of the code, and the time is short.

Comment: jvenema - Picasso made a bull with horns using bicycle parts and it turn out well, I just tried something similar, didn't went anywhere near as expected.. but it saves words

Comment: @c0mrade: like this? http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/demos/position/corner

Comment: I do like it, but I can't use any external libraries, because the person who made this code made it javascript with some prototype functions, I'm sure adding jquery will only complicate things. got anything else ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're wondering about positioning the tooltip, use styling. Give the parent element relative position and the child absolute position in a style sheet:

```
#canvas {
    position: relative;
}
.tooltip {
    position: absolute;
}
```

When you create the tooltip, give it the 'tooltip' class and set its `style.left` and `style.top` properties. Try something like:

```
function click(evt) {
   if (! tooltip) {
       tooltip = document.createElement('div'); // or what-have-you
       tooltip.className += ' tooltip';
   ...
   tooltip.style.left = evt.offsetX + 'px';
   tooltip.style.left = evt.offsetY + 'px';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can capture the mouse position: http://www.codelifter.com/main/javascript/capturemouseposition1.html

Answer (score 0):

Get the x and y coordinates when the mouse is clicked. Position the tooltip[probably will be a div] at the specified x and y coordinates.

To get the coordinates see

[event.clientX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.clientX) and [event.clientY](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.clientY)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I already have those values .. just looking how to position tooltip properly.